# Удалить елемент из масива c++

Tags: c++, arraylist, unreal-engine-4, delete, location

У меня есть массив с FVector

```
FVector locat[] = { FVector(309.998, 100.998, 12), FVector(309.998, 0.998, 12), FVector(309.998, -99.002, 12), FVector(309.998, 100.998, 112), FVector(309.998, 0.998, 112), FVector(309.998, -99.002, 112), FVector(309.998, 100.998, 212), FVector(309.998, 0.998, 212), FVector(309.998, -99.002, 212) };
```

И я хочу избавиться от элемента в массиве похожего на

```
FVector loc = GetActorLocation();
```

Comment: В примере размер массива фиксирован и удалять элементы из него нельзя. Если нужен динамический массив, то используйте `std::vector`.

Comment: В языке Си++ и в Си тип массива не имеет функций удаления и вставки.

Comment: ну тогда что бы при рандомизации этот элемент не учитывался

Comment: как это сделать

Comment: Ну допустим еще можно обменять этот элемент с последним и считать, что в массиве стало на 1 элемент меньше.